# Difference between JsonSerializer().Deserialize() and sonConvert.DeserializeObject()

Tags: json, serialization, c#-4.0, json.net, deserialization

Check these 2 different deserialize operations, and tell me what's the difference in terms of performance. Which one should we use when performance is the first priority?

**Method-1**

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(
    databaseFilePath,
    FileMode.Open,
    FileAccess.Read,
    FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
        var myObject = (MyObjectType)new JsonSerializer().Deserialize(streamReader, typeof(MyObjectType));
    }
}
```

---

**Method-2**

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(
    databaseFilePath,
    FileMode.Open,
    FileAccess.Read,
    FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
        var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObjectType>((await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync()));
    }
}
```

Comment: If  you're going to read from a stream, use the first approach.  It will use resources more efficiently.  The second approach will require more memory because you are forcing it to read the entire stream first before it can even begin to deserialize.

Comment: the problem for the first one; it's not `async`! I would expect a `DeserializeAsync` method in `JsonSerializer`

Comment: Although the Json.Net serializer does not support `async`, the [`JsonTextReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) class does, so you could use that to manually populate your object if needed.  Another option is to switch to [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=netcore-3.1), assuming you are using .Net Core.  But note that `System.Text.Json` is not as full-featured as Json.Net.

Comment: 1) `await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync()` loads the entire file contents into memory as a single string.  If the string is long enough this could impair performance or even run out of memory.  Calling `Deserialize()` directly streams the contents in for better performance.  See: [Performance Tips: Optimize Memory Usage](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#MemoryUsage).

Comment: 2) `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` constructs its serializer via [`JsonSerializer.CreateDefault()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_CreateDefault.htm) which takes into account the global default serializer settings.  `new JsonSerializer()` does not.